# resize Header when user scroll on

Tags: javascript, html, header, resize, onscroll

Here is my code to re size the header on scroll on but it is not working.The didn't set the header to fixed size.But the header size isn't changing i used Javscript and css to do this but it isn't can some please help me to get rid of this error.I struct at this so please some can help me.
Thanks in advance

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>

       <html lang="en">


        <head>


       <title>Request Us Your Requirment</title>




          <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

         <script src="js/classie.js">
         </script>

          <script>

          function init() {

          window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){

            var distanceY = window.pageYOffset ||  document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = 300,
            header = document.querySelector("header");
               if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {

               classie.add(header,"smaller");

                  } 
                 else {

                if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {

                 classie.remove(header,"smaller");

                     }

                         }

                        });

                        }

                window.onload = init();

                </script>

              </head>




                <body>


                 <div id="wrapper">


                  <header>

                <div class="container clearfix">

                 <h1 id="logo">
                  My Site
                 </h1>

                   <nav>

                   <a href="">Services</a>

                <a href="">About Us</a>

                <a href="">Contact Us</a>

                  </nav>

                 </div>

                  </header>


                  <div id="main">

                  <div id="content">

                <section>

                <div class="container">

                  <h1>Request Us Your Requirement</h1>

                        <p>Building a website is a time consuming process.But not now Just get your professional website by contsct us</p>

                <p>We will Provide the best web sites with less cost and within the time.</p>

                      <p>
                  <a href="http://www.facebook.com/vinod.dirishala">Follow Us On FB</a><br>

                     <a href="http://www.twitter.com/vinod.dirishala">Follows Us On Twitter</a>
            </p>

                    </div>

                 </section>

                  <section class="color">

               <div class="container">

             <h1>Why My Site!</h1>

            <p>We will provide Best Quality Webstes</p>

            <p>Low Cost</p>

             <p> How to contact Us</p>

              </div>

             </section>

             </div>

               </div> 



                <footer>

                 <div id="info-bar">

                     <div class="container clearfix">

                   <span class="all-tutorials">

                     </div>

                         </div>

                      </footer>




                         </div>



                         </body>

                            </html>
```

Comment: create fiddle for better help

Comment: here is my jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/VinodD/b39gx6pa/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/b39gx6pa/2/

Replace JavaScript with this:

```
function init() {      
     window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){    
         var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,shrinkOn = 300,header = document.querySelector("header");

         if (distanceY > header.clientHeight/3) {             
            classie.add(header,"smaller");          
         }else {           
            if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {
               classie.remove(header,"smaller");
            }
         }   
     });
}

window.onload = init();
```